# How to increment date by 1 for number of time in sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to increment date by one for some limited number of time.  I was able to increment the current date by 1:

```
Select *, DATEADD(d,1, GETDATE()) From MyTable;
```

But I want to increment the date for number of time in each row Like:

```
ID              Date
1            2012-05-14
2            2012-05-15
3            2012-05-16
```

How can do this?

Comment: Provide some expected input/output?

Comment: Can you just write **ID** instead of **1**?  SELECT DATEADD(dd, ID, GETDATE())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) as the value to the `DATEADD` method.

```
SELECT
    *, 
    DATEADD(d,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC), GETDATE())
FROM 
    MyTable;
```